# Is there a way to make a dynamic model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch

I have a model with 10 fields to model data. But there are some cases where I only have information for 5 or 6 fields and don't use the rest. Is that good practice? is there a better way to make a model adaptable?

This is a project on .Net Framework MVC, and ElasticSearch already configured as DB with NEST middleware.

Here is an example of a model:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace mvcTest.Models
{
    public class Activity
    {
        public string UniqueId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Index { get; set; }
        public string Subtitle { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is how i insert data for each activity, using a controller:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using mvcTest.Models;
using mvcTest.Servicies;
using mvcTest.Repositories;

namespace mvcTest.Controllers
{
    public class InitializeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Initialize()
        {
            var service = new ProjectService();
            service.DeleteAll();

            service.AddBulk(new List<Section> {
                InitializeSectionOne()
            });

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        private Section InitializeSectionOne()
        {
            var section = new Section 
            {
                UniqueId = Utilities.Utilities.GenerateUniqueId(),
                Type = "teacher",
                Index = 1,
                Title = "First Section of Activities",
                Color = "blue",
                Activities = new List<Activity> {
                    InitializeActivity1(),
                    InitializeActivity2()
                }
            };

            return section;
        }

        private Activity InitializeActivity1()
        {
            return new Activity
            {
                UniqueId = Utilities.Utilities.GenerateUniqueId(),
                Title = "Activity 1",
                Index = "Enter",
                Subtitle = "Example",
                Description = "This is a multiple choice test about...",
                DescriptionImage = "/Content/activity-description-img.png"
            };
        }

        private Activity InitializeActivity2()
        {
            return new Activity
            {
                UniqueId = Utilities.Utilities.GenerateUniqueId(),
                Title = "Activity 2",
                Index = "Enter",
                Subtitle = "Example...more....",
                DescriptionImage = "/Content/activity2-description-img.png"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

What happens if it comes an activity that doesn't have `Description`?. Do I need to make a model for each activity?. Or better to use this model and only fill the fields of available info. Does this makes a bad practice or have a consequence I can't see right now?

This is an example of 1 fields. What if there are more than 5 or 10 unused fields set in the model.

Comment: Maybe ExpandoObject is what you are looking for??

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks!. Well i'm not sure i understood well that class to tell if it's what i'm looking for. Is there a good example. Anyway i'm searching for a video about this.... Thanks for leading a start on this...